# error in every new android project with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an android project and it gives me errors
 and errors appear only if I have more than one android project (R cannot be resolved to a variable ) and if i import it errors change to (R.menu.**main**,R.layout.**activity_main**,R.id.**action_settings**

[image]

Comment: show the expanded view of errors. We just see in screenshot that you have 5 errors. What are the errors?

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your XML that needs fixed.

Comment: please expand the errors and write it down - not only a screenshot!

Comment: well if you use android studio you could click on the (R) with the underlined red and choose a fix. Get Android Studio, Eclipse had its day

Comment: i added screenshot with errors

Answer (score 0):

**Change android:minSdkVersion to 11** in your androidmanifest.xml. Yours is currently 8 which does not allow the call your are trying to make in onCreateView() method. **First error in your screenshot clearly says it.**

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="11"
   android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

target SDK could be what you want.

Based on your comment if you still want to continue using API level 8. You should determine the API level at runtime and then call the method that works for the Android version on device. Read this for more info: [Check System Version at Runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html)

Comment: what if i want target that SDK 8 ??

Comment: then you will need to find a corresponding method call that is failing for SDK < 11 and call that when SDK is less than 11.

Comment: check updated answer, but first see if changing it to 11 helps you get rid of the errors. you can then revert it back to support 8 by checking the system version at runtime.

Comment: that link didnt help,i tryed to change targetsdkversion to lower number but still same errors i also tried to raise minsdkversion but no change in errors

Comment: Do a clean project; and in eclipse you will need to wait a bit for the selected API Level to load from SDK.